# Feature Request: Create new tags during question edit

Tags: feature-request, support, tags

Is there a way to add a new tag without adding it in a new question? I think the site would benefit from the tag addition of "isolation-forest" as I have seen a few of these questions pop up recently. I can add tags but can only do so when asking a question.

As shown in the comments below:

> I guess the comment is that maybe as a feature request, users with
>   sufficient experience should be able to add tags during edit.

Answer (score 2):

**Not possible**

However, you can add the tag to an existing question.

Comment: The only problem is that I have not asked any questions on this subject, only answered them.

Comment: You can propose an edit to that question

Comment: This would only work if the person asking the question has the reputation to add tags?

Comment: yes. That'd help in ensuring min. experience on the site before anyone can create new tags.

Comment: I guess the comment is that maybe as a feature request, users with sufficient experience should be able to add tags during edit.